# Problem with disabling submit buttons on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I am using the jQuery disable on submit plug-in but I have a problem. If I disable the submit buttons they don't get passed back to the server so I cant tell which button was pressed. Is this normal? Is there anything I can do about it?

I really don't want to retool my web site so I have to set a variable on form submission to tell which button was pressed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround I just found in [a jQuery forum](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/428f1d3c5f459506?pli=1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sendSearch").click(function() {
            $('#loadingDiv').show();
            $('#sendSearch').attr("disabled", "disabled");

            // these two lines are the workaround
            this.form.submit();
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it does, otherwise I wouldn't post it. In which browser does it not work? Version?

Comment: +1 not sure why that got voted down but imho thats the best as it works with or without javascript

Comment: Have you tried this with an ASP.NET web form?  Didn't think so.

Comment: shouldn't it be return false at the end? / so it doesn't goes on to submit through that code path as well.

Answer (score 4):

[How to Disable the Submit Button of a Web Form](http://blog.josh420.com/archives/2008/02/how-to-disable-the-submit-button-ofweb-form.aspx)

This method hides the button instead of disabling it, and programmatically inserts a disabled <button> tag to make it *appear* just like the submit button was disabled.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the submit via jquery and disable the button afterwards:

```
<input type="submit" value="do it!" onclick="$('#mainform').submit(); $(this).attr('disabled','disabled' ); $('#pleasewait').show();" />
```

EDIT:
I forgot form.submit() is not asynchronous. You can do an ajax request instead:

```
$.ajax({
url: "someurl",
type:"POST",
cache: false,
dataType: "json",
success:gotIt,
async:true,
timeout:240000,
error:ajaxError,
data:$("#mainform").serialize()
});
```

or you could just .hide() the button, or after clicking it setting a non-functional onClick() handler and styling it to look disabled.

Comment: Don't i have to supply the post parameters do this ajax call too?

Answer (score 0):

Be more simple :)

```
var formid="#id-form-if-exists"; //Put here the id if exists
$("form"+formid).submit(function(){$("form"+formid+" input").attr("disabled",false);});
```

YEAH